# postgres acquire row-level lock

Tags: postgresql, locking

How do I acquire a row-specific lock in Postgres?

According to the documentation, I can acquire a *table* lock, but I don't want to lock the whole table; I only care about monitoring a specific *row* in a given transaction.

My use case is that I want to:

- read a row
- perform some (potentially expensive, potentially race-condition) operations that prepare new rows for another table
- when I'm finally ready to insert/update these new rows, I want to make sure no other process beat me to the punch, so I think I want to:

  - acquire a row-level lock on the same row I read earlier
  - see if the `version` or `state` or column like that is the same as when I read it earlier
  - if it *is* the same, I want to insert/update into the other table, then increment this `version`, then release the lock
  - if it is *not* the same `version`, then I want to abort - I don't care about my possible new/updated rows, they are stale and I don't want to save them (so: do nothing, release the lock)

But, I don't want to lock the entire table for this whole period; I just want to lock that one specific row. I cannot figure out how to do that based on [numerous](http://blog.nordeus.com/dev-ops/postgresql-locking-revealed.htm) . [blog](http://big-elephants.com/2013-09/exploring-query-locks-in-postgres/) . [posts](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/postgresql-locking-revealed-petar-partlov/) and [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-lock.html) . [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html#locking-rows)

All I want is an example query that shows me how to explicitly row-level lock.

Comment: `select ... for update`

Comment: I think you're more after a [Transaction](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/transaction-iso.html) than everything else...

Comment: To follow up to @a_horse_with_no_name's comment you may want to include NOWAIT.  In 9.5+ you can also use SKIP LOCKED.  These are useful in preventing your code from waiting for another long running process working on the same row

Comment: Ah, ok, I think `select ... for update` inside a `transaction` is what I needed; I just was having trouble piecing that together from the docs on my own. Thanks!

Comment: @Dan - I saw `NOWAIT` in the documentation; I think that would be case-specific. I'll try to keep my `select ... for update` and `update (others)` as concise as possible, so the lock shouldn't be held for very long. The slower process happens outside Postgres, and should happen outside the lock (at least in the case I'm considering).